# What does the heartbeat line in my torrc mean?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, bandwidth, log

I know that the Tor logs are in /var/log/tor. I have a question as to what one of the lines in the log means though. I see something along these lines:

```
 Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 4 days 18:00 hours, with 440 circuits open. I've sent 128.72 GB and received 126.85 GB.
 Heartbeat: Tor's uptime is 5 days 0:00 hours, with 483 circuits open. I've sent 159.72 GB and received 157.45 GB.
```

Does this mean I have sent that much data total since I started the relay a few days ago, or does that mean that from the time in the first heartbeat I posted, to the time in the second heartbeat I posted, I have sent 31 GB of data?

Basically, have I sent a total of 159.75 GB and received 157.45 GB of data since the relay first started? Or was that how much data I sent and received since the last heartbeat in a 6 hour period? That might be unclear, and if it is, let me know and I will try to explain more clearly. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those logs mean that you have transmitted 159 GB and received 157 GB as a total during the 5 days, which means you have sent only 31 GB in the period between the 2 log messages.

Comment: You are the man, Linostar. Thanks for answering my questions!